# Match one sheet figures with another on excel

Tags: excel

Okay as you can see from the below screenshots. I have got 3 sheets in excel. 2014, 2013 and comparison. Basically in the comparison tab I intend to compare figures from 2014 with 2013 for several sites for my business. So if you check the "comparison" image you will see initials of where my business sites are located accross the UK, eg ABZ = Aberdeen etc. and I am analysing the revenue, cons and weight per week for every site, so as you can imagine quite alot of information. I have condensed it for this example.

But is there a formula that will allow me in the "comparison" pic to key in all the information from the "2014" , "2013" information without having to manually sit there and add the formala ='2013'!c5 wich gives me the value for the 1st week for revenue but if i want it for week 2 I have to change the formula manually to ='2013'!c13  .  Check images for clarity.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kitfyy3i2pbso1j/2013.JPG?dl=0  =  2013 tab

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v9xwnmlwrm899cr/2014.JPG?dl=0   = 2014 tab

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mhvbmmecwcsydyi/Comparison.JPG?dl=0 = comparison tab